# windows-phone 8.1 page closed event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

i'm writing a WP\Win-8.1 application and i'm trying to find the best way to detect when my Page is being closed by the user, something like OnPagClosed but i can't find such event\function.
Is there such a function or do i need to listen to some other delegates?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `OnNavigatedFrom` and `OnNavigatingFrom` methods in your page. These are called when the user is navigation from your page to another.

See MSDN for reference about both methods - [OnNavigatedFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom.aspx) and [OnNavigatingFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatingfrom.aspx).

These two methods differ when they are called (before and after the navigation from the current page) and `OnNavigatingFrom` allows you to cancel the navigation.

Comment: Be sure to also check the [navigation direction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationmode.aspx) if that matters. Also depending on what you're trying to do, you may need to handle suspension and/or activation events as well.